# Execution environment setting in run configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When creating a launch configuration you can specify an Execution environment, how is that more specifically used? I assume it ends up as a parameter to Java?

What are the consequences if we have a plugin built with JavaSE-1.8 execution environment, and run an application using that plugin and run it with execution environment JRE-1.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:**

It won't run. Execution environment says the code is intended to be executed in a certain Java implementation. This affects both: the bytecode version your sources get compiled into and Java Class Library you're code is intended to use. The setting is used by IDE (not sure all IDEs use it - Eclipse does) to make sure you only write code possible to execute in a give EE.

**Bytecode incompatibility example:**

Java 8 added lambda support - if you use it your bytecode will have labmda related instructions and it will not execute in older JVMs.

**JCL incompatibility example:**

Java 8 introduced URLPermission class. If you refer to it in your code and try to run it against older Java Class Library you'll get an exception. Even if you compile your code into older bytecode version. The class is simply not accessible in older JCL.

**Links:**

Eclipse community has a lot of resources on Java Execution Environments - read about it [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Execution_Environments).

Comment: Makes sense. Turns out my in my particular situation a simple Java app was started that in turned launched Eclipse using Java 8. So the execution environment of JRE1-1 was never really relevant for our plugins.

Answer (score 1):

1.8 to 1.1? so much of discord in versions? Anyways, launch configuration has data about path of jre, depenedency jars and location of files where parameters needed by program are stored.

if you change env, your code may not be source compatible or you may get errors like 'file not found /class not found'.